# Jest is throwing type errors from dependent node_modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, babeljs

I am using Jest + Enzyme for unit testing of react application, and I am also using my company owned dependent libraries as node_modules , those are in Javascript (ES6) but my application and my test scripts are in TypeScript, so here while running tests Jest is throwing type errors from those libraries ( node_modules) as you see in below picture, Abstract.jsx is coming from dependent node_modules
[image]

I am using below setting in jest config which is not helping, how to fix this continuous type errors. please help

```
"globals": {
  "ts-jest": {
    "diagnostics": false
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

> , Abstract.jsx is coming from dependent node_modules

The module should come with *compiled* `.js` files. It seems that it doesn't

## Options

Pick one:

- Ask the module author to publish built `.js` files (recommended)
- Build them yourself. Add a `.jsx` to `.js` build workflow into your setup.

Comment: thank you for responding, two things ,i am wondering how regular build is working (before unit test cases) with .jsx , why ts compiler is not throwing such errors. second thing, i upgraded babel to 7.0+ which is throwing ".sourceMap is an alias for .sourceMaps, cannot use both" error would you please help me if you are aware of where to remove sourcemaps, i haven't used sourcemaps in babel.config.js ,i commented devtool as well in webpack.config.js ,

Comment: Here is my babel.config.js module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: "node 11.0", modules: "commonjs" }],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  env: {
    test: {
      presets: [["@babel/preset-env"]],
      plugins: [
        ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"],
        ["@babel/proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }],
        ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { decoratorsBeforeExport:true }]
      ]
    }
  }
};

Comment: Here webpack configuration for babel_loader module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(tsx?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: ['babel-loader']
      },